# How to store a user defined gesture in a database without using GestureBuilder

Tags: android, gesture

I'm making a application that can take as input a gesture from the user, store it in a database(not necessarily database, a file will also work fine) and then retrieve it whenever the user wants.
 After plenty of searching all I could find was people using GestureBuilder to store some predefined gestures. I want my application to be highly dynamic so that whatever gesture the user enters is stored. Also I've seen people posting this link http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html
 which is no more functional(don't know why google just removed this page from their documentation). Please help.

Comment: This is probably the link you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html

Comment: Nops. This link doesn't talk anything about gesture builder and certainly not what I'm looking for :) .

Comment: study [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html) package

Comment: Isn't there a well defined documentation for this package where they tell you how to actually code this ?

Comment: so what's unclear with `android.gesture.*` classes ?

Comment: It doesn't tell me how can I take input gesture from a user and store it

Comment: `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView` ? `android.gesture.GestureLibrary` ?

Comment: How come you got to know about these classes, The documentation doesn't contain even a single page that talks in general how to use these classes

Comment: how come? study [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html) package